# Dropdown component on header toolbar of fullcalendar in react js without jquery

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, dropdown

I am using fullcalendar in react js and want to display dropdown in it's header toolbar. I have a separate component for dropdown and want to integrate it in the header. Is there any way to do that without using jquery I checked their documentation but there is nothing like that. We can create only custom buttons and can't even pass any tags in those buttons. There have just limited options .

Comment: What makes you think jQuery would be necessary anyway? Native JS can create a dropdown list just the same as jQuery can. I don't really understand that part of your question. If the real question is "can you put a dropdown into the header of fullCalendar", then the answer is "not using the API, but maybe if you inject the element into the relevant part of the DOM". The exact method (jQuery, native JS, some other helper library) of making the element and adding it to the DOM is irrelevant to that fact.

Comment: Yes I want to inject dropdown component in DOM to display it in header. I mentioned JQuery because all the solutions I found included JQuery and it's not preferrable to use JQuery in react js. I have tried accesing dom nodes but couldn't find any way to access toolbar and inject dropdown in it.

Comment: Well the header is just a DOM element so there's no reason it wouldn't be accessible with standard JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe you can show us exactly what you tried, and then we can try to clarify why it didn't work as you expected, and then we can tell you how to fix it.